# how can I reshape jq output?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json data:

```
[
     {"name":"JSON", "good":true}, 
     {"name":"XML", "good":false},
     {"name":"JSON", "good":false},
     {"name":"HTML", "good":false},
     {"name":"XML", "good":true},
     {"name":"XML", "good":false}
  ]
```

by using :

```
jq '.[] | select(.name =="XML") | .good', result will be :
false
true
false
```

How can I make it like **[false,true,false]** as a record?

Answer (score 2):

Just try wrap the whole expression within an array constructor, `[]`

```
jq '[.[] | select(.name =="XML") | .good]'
[
  false,
  true,
  false
]
```

Or in a same line using the `--compact-output` flag

```
jq --compact-output '[.[] | select(.name =="XML") | .good ]'
[false,true,false]
```

Answer (score 1):

In short: gather the results as an array, and use the -c option, e.g.

```
$ jq -c 'map( select(.name =="XML") | .good )'
```

Output:

```
[false,true,false]
```